# I want to integrate amazon chime in my .net mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I want to integrate amazon chime in my .net MVC web application but can't find any documentation or steps to integrate. on the AWS site there are samples available only of node.js. If anyone has worked on the same please help.

Comment: Did you find any information for this? We are trying to add it to a Visual Studio project as well. I cannot figure out how to webpack the npm files and make them accessible to the client? There is NO documentation on this.